# bash aws commands do not wait until completion

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a bash script on a local machine that sends a series of commands to run some scripts on an ec2 before terminating. A snippit is below:

```
cat ec2-commands.sh
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","aws s3 cp s3://test/scripts/run_model1.sh ."]
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["sudo bash /home/ec2-user/run_model1.sh"]
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids "${instanceid}"
```

The 'run_model1.sh' script takes ~ 3 hours to finish. However, from the local machine, there is no waiting for the 'run_model1.sh' to finish before terminating the instance. In other words, the local machine sends the command to run 'run_model1.sh' and immediately after the ec2 instance starts running the script, this counts as a 'successful' send command and the local script sends a command to terminate instance executes shortly after.  How am I able to have some sort of 'watch' or 'wait' so that the script would look something like the following:

```
cat ec2-commands.sh
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["cd /home/ec2-user","aws s3 cp s3://test/scripts/run_model1.sh ."]
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --instance-ids "${instanceid}" --parameters commands=["sudo bash /home/ec2-user/run_model1.sh"]
[command here to wait for 'run_model1.sh' on the ec2 instance to finish]
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids "${instanceid}"
```

Or is there an option with ssm send-command that will wait until the script is finished on the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait on a command to finish using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/wait/command-executed.html):

```
aws ssm wait command-executed
```

However there's a hard limit of 100 seconds, which is well below the 3 hours you say your script takes to execute.

Why not just send a single command that does everything that the instance needs to do, and add a `shutdown -h now` command at the end?

---

Otherwise, you might [subscribe to SSM Run Command status events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-notifications.html), and have something like a Lambda function send the next command.

Comment: This needs awscli 1.19+